# major php issues

Tags: php, sql, database, authentication

I am trying to create a simple login system. When I run the login form (with the correct username and password) it doesn't seem to run the php. Any suggestions?

```
<?php
$host="linuxserver"; // Host name
$username="jparry2"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="jparry2"; // Database name
$tbl_name="customer"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysqli_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysqli_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file “login_success.php”
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>

<html>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

edit added login form code

```
<html>
<head><title>Login</title></head>
<body>


<form action='checklogin.php'
                method='POST' style='margin: .5in'>
    <p><label for='user_name' style='font-weight: bold;
          padding-bottom: 1em'>USER ID: </label>
       <input type='text' name='myusername' id='myusername'
          value='' /></p>
    <p><label for='password' style= 'font-weight: bold'>Password: </label>
       <input type='password' name='mypassword' id='mypassword'
          value='' /></p>
    <p><input type='submit' value='Login'> </p>
       <input type='hidden' name='sent' value='yes'/>

<a href= "/home/jparry2/public_html/register.php">Register</a>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the browser's source code say? What do you see there?

Comment: I think you should specify way more information then this. For example what OS are you using. What is problem? No output shown. Does a simple <?phpinfo(); ?> work?

Comment: Can you please add code for your login form?

Comment: a more specific title would be nice

Comment: I've changed a few things and now the browser brings up a dialogue box asking me to download the php. I'm using linux and opera.

Comment: You will have to check if you have php installed and configured correctly. Also, telling us that you  *Changed a few things* to solve your *major php problem* isn´t helping us much.

Comment: We really need all the errors messages you get if you want us to help you...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your browser asks you to download the php file it means the php interpreter is not being invoked. i.e. you don't have it installed or configured correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting any error message? Seems ok to me. Have you tried echoing something in the if-block for example? That might help you understand what's wrong.

Some things you could check or try:

- Have you got error reporting on?
- Put `var_dump($_POST); die(); on the top of the page to see if the $_POST variables are submitted correctly.
- Make sure you are not outputting anything to the browser before the `header()` function. If you have error_reporting off and you outputted something to the browser, using `header()` will result in a fatal error which could cause a blank white page.

A few other notes from your code:

- You don't need to put variables inside double quotes, they work on their own: `mysqli_select_db("$db_name")` becomes `mysqli_select_db($db_name)`
- You don't need to `stripslashes()` if you're doing `mysql_real_escape_string`. The latter will handle the job on its own.

Answer (score 1):

In some browsers, the `Location` header is case-sensitive, and thus your `header("location:login_success.php");` call might not be working (a [comment](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#79028) on the [`header` documentation page](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) suggests that this occurs in IE7). Try capitalizing the `l` in Location.

Comment: IIRC, In most of browsers headers follow the standard: Uppercase Names and space after ":".

Answer (score 1):

You don't do any "session_start()", so your session can't be used.

Maybe you need it to started in your "login_success.php" script.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Daniel, by revising `header("Location: login_success.php");`

Also, as a side note since at the time of writing this, it wasn't clearly explained what didn't work, but you when adding session variables you need to have `session_start()`.

Also try to use `$_SESSION['variable']` since `session_register()` is deprecated as of PHP 5.30 taken from [PHP: session_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php) try something like this

```
if($count==1){
session_start();
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file “login_success.php”
$_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['mypassword'] = $mypassword;
session_write_close(); // makes sure nothing was lost during redirect
header('Location: nextpage.php');
}
```